# Nested anonymous functions including arrayfun

Tags: matlab, nested, vectorization, anonymous-function

I'm trying to do something like the following code:

```
k = linspace(a,b);
x = c:0.01:d;
% k and x are of different sizes
f = @(s) arrayfun(@(t) normcdf(s, b0+b1*t, sigma), x);
y = arrayfun(f, k);
```

I get the following error

> Error using arrayfun   Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1,
>   output 1.   Set `'UniformOutput'` to `false`.

I'm trying to avoid using a for loop for each element in k.
Also, for each result matching an element in k, I need to do another small calculation

Example with a loop:

```
for i=1:m  % m is the number of elements in k
    f = @(t) normcdf(k(i), b0+b1*x, sigma);
    y = arrayfun(f, x);
    res(i) = trapz(x,y);
end
```

any idea how can I get the same result as the for loop with the first method?
and why am I getting the error?

Comment: first try to do what the error suggests and set `'UniformOutput'` to `'false'` -> `y = arrayfun(f, k,'UniformOutput','false');` Second, why you want to avoid the loop? I think you won't save processing time in this case.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thank you! I'm a bit new to matlab so not familiar with all the options.
had to struggle a bit with it but now it works..

about the loops.. my course teacher asked to avoid loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
k = linspace(a,b);
x = c:0.01:d;
[X,K] = meshgrid(x,k)

y = arrayfun(@(p,t) normcdf(p, b0+b1*t, sigma), K(:), X(:))
res = cumtrapz(x,y)
```

Untested though as you gave no example data and desired results. Maybe you need to swap the order of `x` and `k` as well as `X` and `K` to get the desired result. (or use `ndgrid` instead of `meshgrid`, has the same effect)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I ended up using @thewaywewalk's answer with a few adjustments
your method gives a single number result while I need a vector of m results.. maybe it could be adjusted but not sure
anyway it seems to work now

Comment: what do you mean? `cumtrapz` returns a vector.

Comment: I might be wrong, I've experimented with it a bit and didn't get the result I was looking for. Maybe I did something wrong. assume x is of size 1,49 and k is of size 1,100. I get y of size 4900,1 but It's supposed to be 490,100 (or 100,490). So res gets size of 4900,1 instead of 100,1 (or 1,100). Any idea how to change it so it gives what I've said?  hope that was clear enough

Comment: I've just noticed that you gave both the answers haha! 
For some reason I thought it was 2 different people before... 
It's currently working with the `'Uniform Output'` fix but would be nice to test with the `mehsgrid`

Comment: OK.. I've used `vev2mat` and now it's working with the `meshgrid`. And it's the best performance method as well so Thanks :)